# What are the C++ things one should know about polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

When using Polymorphism in C++, what are the important facts to know about it.

Like, for example, when casting from `derived` to `base`, what should one be aware of?

When is an upcast possible, and when not?
When do you need a 'virtual' destructor and when not?

What do you need to be aware of when using pointers from base to derived objects?

There was a [discussion in the C++ lounge](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1235055#1235055) just now about the `sizeof(*this)` with polymorphic types, which inspired me to ask this question.

An "obscure" fact such as this one:

"If you have a Derived that's hidden behind a Base&, then the static type is Base, while the dynamic type is Derived."

Is also the kind of things I am looking for, in this question.

Comment: You must be aware of the *slicing problem* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: Have a look at the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) - and specifically the sections on inheritance. Plenty of important facts are being described in detail there.

Answer (score 5):

Read "Effective C++" and "More Effective C++".  Answering your question here would literally require writing a small book.

Comment: +1 for pointing out Scott Meyers "classics", ;-)